# Two errors related to npx create-react-app and npm i -g create-react-app (-g is not recognized) explained in full detail below

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, create-react-app, npx

I am unable to use `npm i -g create-react-app` when I type this it does works but returns an error:

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand, operable program or batch file
```

and second error is when i type `npx create-react-app app-name`:

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand, operable program or batch file.
npx: command not found: create-react-app
```

Here are my local and system environment PATH variables:

Local environment variable:
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;`

System environment variable:
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;`

I already tried installing and reinstalling it .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a node is not installed or registered correctly.  You can do all the classics:

Uninstall and re-install node

Ensure your npm path is install with env paths:

```
%AppData%\npm
```

Ensure C:\Program Files\nodejs is within your environment variables.  Within "Environment Variables". Click "Edit system environment variables".  Click "Environment Variables".  In "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include C:\Program Files\nodejs. Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a ;

Close any command prompts, etc..  an alternative is to:

```
set NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

When you manually browse to, C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin do you see anything.

The second error is because node is not registered, so if you fix the first one the second one should go away

Comment: I tried reinstalling already . Do i have to run rem for future ...... in cmd ? also I dont see anything such as NODE_PATH my envrionment variables are stored in PATH Also I do see stuff and files in  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin @Jon Jones